# Windows WriteFileGather function set last error as ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, windows, iocp

Example code to reproduce my problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  HANDLE hdl = CreateFile("test.file", GENERIC_WRITE,
                          FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS,
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL  |
                          FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING |
                          FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                          NULL);
  char data[4096] = {0};
  DWORD written = 0;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data); ++i)
    data[i] = 'a' + (i % 26);

  OVERLAPPED async_hdl = {0};
  FILE_SEGMENT_ELEMENT segs[3] = {0};

  segs[0].Buffer = PtrToPtr64(data);
  segs[1].Buffer = PtrToPtr64(data);

  if(!WriteFileGather(hdl, segs, 8192, NULL, &async_hdl)) {
    cout << "Last error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    cout << "overlapped internal status: " << async_hdl.Internal << endl;
    // Last error: 87
    // overlapped internal status: 259
  }
  CloseHandle(hdl);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with Visual Studio 2012 and test on Windows 7. As inlined comment, the `WriteFileGather` function always sets the last error as `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (87) and `Internal` field of the OVERLAPPED struct is `259`.

What did I miss?

Comment: You missed that `GetLastError` is only reliable if the function returned an error code. Unless `WriteFileGather` returns 0, nothing went wrong, and `GetLastError()` should be ignored.

Comment: @molbdnilo Excuse me for being misleading. I've updated the code to check return value of `WriteFileGather`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN: `aSegmentArray` ...system memory page and must be aligned on a system memory page size boundary. Use `_aligned_malloc()` instead of stack memory.

Comment: I just missed that line! You saved the day!